# Installing Windows 8 Dev Preview on a Macbook Pro

Tags: installation, virtualbox, macbook-pro, windows-8-preview

Is it possible to install Windows 8 Developer Preview on a Macbook Pro. I'm trying to do this using the `WindowsDeveloperPreview-64bit-English-Developer.iso` file with VirtualBox but fail during the installation process with it trying to expand files.

Any hints on how to install Windows 8 Dev Preview on the Macbook Pro?

Comment: I am running it under vmware  fusion 4 with no problems. just told it was a windows 7 64 bit host.

Comment: You might see the answer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/335654/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-8-using-microsoft-virtual-pc.  VirtualBox might not have the needed support.

Comment: @Shinrai that leads to VirtualPC, and searching for info it seems that Win 8 should work on VirtualBox. The question is if it's possible to run on VirtualBox in MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [VirtualBox wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)

> Supported host operating systems include Linux, **Mac OS X**, Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Solaris, and OpenSolaris; there is also a port to FreeBSD (only OSE version).

So virtual box should run, [ymmv](http://www.google.com/search?q=your%20mileage%20may%20vary)...

Now you should follow guides such as this for configuring VirualBox for Windows 8 Developer Preview:

> Step by step guide here : http://www.sysprobs.com/guide-install-windows-8-virtualbox

Main configuration elements:

- Select Windows 7 as option in VirtualBox
- Enable VT-x and Nesting Paging
- Enable PAE/NX
- Enable IO APIC
- Enable 3D Acceleration, you can enable 2D Acceleration also

Comment: Accepted as answer, even though I forgot one of the configuration options there is also some kind of bug that halts the installation of Windows 8 when you're switching desktops and doing something else on Mac OS X. Not sure if Windows 8 installation program, OS X Lion or VirtualBox causes this behavior. You can complete the installation if you can leave the MacBook Pro while installing Win 8.