# Virtual PC 2007: A internal virtual machine error (3) has occoured. Please restart the machine

Tags: windows-10-preview

I'm trying to install Windows 10 Technical Preview on Microsoft Virutal PC 2007 SP1.

When I start it up to the windows logo for the restart it says:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 cannot run Windows 10, as the virtual/emulated hardware doesn't supply what's needed by Windows 8 and above.

Instead, try another VM software package that supports Windows 8+ (like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)).

For more information, check out this other SU question: [Is it possible to install Windows 8 using Microsoft Virtual PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/335654/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-8-using-microsoft-virtual-pc)