# Windows 10 virtual machine on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtual-machine

Every morning, there's a little window urging me to upgrade to Windows 10 hanging off the taskbar.  Is there a straightforward way to create a Windows 10 VM under Windows 7 x64, so I could see what it's like, without having to take the plunge?

Again, I'm using Windows 7 x64, not Windows 8.

Comment: Make a [system image backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/back-up-programs-system-settings-files#1TC=windows-7) of 7, take the plunge, restore 7 if you dislike 10.  Windows 10 will also store your old Windows install for 30 days after the upgrade, in case you want to roll back.

Comment: Are you guys who marked this as a duplicate certain that there are no differences or nuances to this question relative to Windows 7 versus Window 8?

Comment: I speak as one who has taken the plunge (too) many times. Shutting questions down as duplicates should be done sparingly. There are differences between 7 and 8.  Windows 8 supports HyperV, Windows 7 doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here.  Please explain (other than the host OS) how your question is any different than the duplicate?  They both seem equally broad...  As I see it you're only asking "Is there a straightforward way to create a Windows 10 VM under Windows?"  and so the answer is the same: install a VM program that can run Win10 as a guest (ie: VirtualBox), and install Windows 10 in the VM (use the Win10 Evaluation version if you want to avoid using/having a license during testing). VirtualBox works under windows 7 and 8, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You can get a 90 day evaluation of [Windows 10 Enterprise](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise), and install it with any virtualisation host of your preference.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides pre-built images of several combinations of OS's from XP to Win 10 and their supported IE browsers. These are very useful to have an batch of VM's for compatibility testing. Microsoft provides these VMs for the current VM platforms.
[Microsoft's Virtual Machine image download page](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/)

Comment: Thanks. How would I find out whether Windows Virtual PC has already been installed on my Windows 7 x64 machine?

Comment: Also, is one of the four VM hosts in the dropdown on that page another name for Virtual PC? Or are these images not usable with Virtual PC?

Comment: @mrblint You may want to check out this SU question: [Virtual PC 2007: A internal virtual machine error (3) has occoured. Please restart the machine](http://superuser.com/questions/823095/virtual-pc-2007-a-internal-virtual-machine-error-3-has-occoured-please-resta) and/or [Is it possible to install Windows 8 using Microsoft Virtual PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/335654/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-8-using-microsoft-virtual-pc)

Comment: @Techie007: Thanks for that link.